# Convert string to number field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Database field whose datatype is String in Crystal Reports. How can I  convert it to a number value?

Answer (score 33):

Within Crystal, you can do it by creating a formula that uses the `ToNumber` function. It might be a good idea to code for the possibility that the field might include non-numeric data - like so:

```
If NumericText ({field}) then ToNumber ({field}) else 0
```

Alternatively, you might find it easier to convert the field's datatype within the query used in the report.