# Summarize the fields in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have a column name "totalcost" , the datatype is nvarchar.. it accepts numbers and the word "Not Applicable"

is it possible to SUMMARIZE that column?
i have a problem because all data in this column are not all integer.

Comment: are numbers and characters mixed in single field or there is either character or number in single field

Answer (score 0):

You can create an formular field to clarify your value, set it's value to 0 if "Not Applicable". Then, Summarize on new formular field.

Comment: is it ok to summarize a column that is set to nvarchar?

Comment: You can try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953435/covert-a-string-to-number-field-in-crystal-report

Comment: on my column "totalcost" i want to set the whole number with 2 decimal places.. like the number "2" will be 2.00

Comment: this column totalcost has a data that is whole number and "Not Applicable"